# Which json type can be used with the restangular for the get request

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I have created a simple demoapp and it seems to work perfectly file.

The demoapp uses restangular for the get request.

```js
/* the emp.json file from where the data is coming*/

[
{"id":1,
"subject":"#aashima"
},
{"id":2,
"subject":"#aansh"
},
{"id":3,
"subject":"#artle"
},
{"id":4,
"subject":"#harish"
}
]
```

```html
<!doctype html >
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
 
    <title>Restangular</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">  
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/restangular/1.5.1/restangular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="IndexCtrl as omega" ng-cloak>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="result in omega.people">
                <span ng-bind="result.subject"></span>
            </li>
            
        </ul>
        <span ng-bind="omega.hero"></span>
    </div>
 
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app', ['restangular'])
            .config(function(RestangularProvider) {
 RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl("js");
            });
 
        app.controller('IndexCtrl', function( Restangular) {
            var self=this;
        
            Restangular.all('emp.json').getList().then(function(result) {
            self.people = result;
            });
            
           
            
        });
         
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The app works perfectly but the problem in here is that the json response from my backend will be something like this

{"user":[
{"id":1,
"subject":"#aashima"
},
{"id":2,
"subject":"#aansh"
},
{"id":3,
"subject":"#artle"
}
]
}`

I tired to integrate the code  with this json response, does Restangular supports this  json and if it does do I need a different approach !!!

Comment: need to implement a response interceptor where you would unwrap the data

Comment: response interceptor  !!!!!

Comment: Can you provide me any example or code correction for this code can guide me better

Comment: https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#addresponseinterceptor

Comment: @charlietfl , because I tired to grasp the  github for this but it didnt work out

Comment: also example in FAQ  https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#my-response-is-actually-wrapped-with-some-metadata-how-do-i-get-the-data-in-that-case

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl  I integrate the  response interceptors and now it is working still had issues with the working of the  responseInterceptors  but yes as of right now It will work